# Send User detail to his email when django admin creates user

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to send all the user data to his/her provided email whenever admin creates a user detail through django admin.I reckon post_save signal should be used for such process.But my post_save signal is not called on console and also could not send all the user details after admin has created .What have i done wrong ?

**Models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def send_user_data_when_created_by_admin(sender, **kwargs):
    import inspect
    records = []
    for record in inspect.stack():
      print('record',record)
      records.append(record[3])
    if record[3]=='get_response':
      request = record[0].f_locals['request']
      first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
      print('first name is',first_name)
      last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
      address = request.POST.get('address')
      email = request.POST.get('email')
      html_content = "your first name:%s <br> last name:%s <br> address:%s"
      from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
      message=EmailMessage('welcome',html_content %(first_name,last_name,address),from_email,[email])
      message.content_subtype='html'
      message.send()

class userbase(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the first name of user"))
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the last name"))
  address = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the address"))
  contact = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the contact"))
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the email"))
  username = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the username"))
  password = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the strong password"))

  def __str__(self):
    return (self.username)
```

Comment: You should change `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` to `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` in your settings file to see the email sent if the signal gets called at all

Comment: I did not get the first name in console as i have printed it to see if its working or not . What might be wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your function to this

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=UserProfile)
def send_user_data_when_created_by_admin(sender, instance, **kwargs):

      first_name = instance.user.first_name
      print('first name is',first_name)
      last_name = instance.user.last_name
      address = instance.address
      email = instance.user.email
      html_content = "your first name:%s <br> last name:%s <br> address:%s"
      message=EmailMessage(subject='welcome',body=html_content %(first_name,last_name,address),to=[email])
      message.content_subtype='html'
      message.send()
```

your model should be this

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  address = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the address"))
  contact = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the contact"))
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)

  def __str__(self):
    return (self.username)
```

so whenever you want to save a new object, you use this

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, contact=contact, address=address)
user.save()
```

where username, email, password, first_name, last_name, contact and address are the cleaned_data of their respective field value from the form you created.

You could design your admin to be forced to create a UserProfile while creating a User by using these lines in your **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from account.models import UserProfile


class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False


class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)


admin.site.unregister(get_user_model())
admin.site.register(get_user_model(), UserProfileAdmin)
```

Should in case you run into any error kindly let me know

Comment: i understand every part of your code except the user = User.objects....Is it same as creating the user from admin panel ? Because i want an admin to create a user with the details like first name,last name,etc.

Comment: hey it worked for me but instead of instance.user.first_name i did instance.first_name and i get the desired result.I will mark your answer as solved.

Comment: you could also design your admin to create a UserProfile whenever a User is being created from the admin page by displaying the UserProfile table under the django User table. check my answer for the code.

Comment: This app is just about creating the user profile by admin through admin panel and sending the created user profile to that user in his/her email.So i dont think there will be use of User in models.py.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Cheers!