# How to change content_subtype to html in django email_user

Tags: python, django, email, html-email

I read about django email confirmation form this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html#sign-up-with-confirmation-mail). Now I need to send html mail not a simple string. I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34895780/8258902) on how to send html email in django. Is there a way to change content_subtype to html in this tutorial email sending approach? or any other way to send html mail in this approach?

```
current_site = get_current_site(request)
subject = 'Activate Your Account'
message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
    'user': user,
    'domain': current_site.domain,
    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
    })
user.email_user(subject, message)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried and get my answer, hope it can help someone else.

`email_user` function is this:

```
def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
    """Send an email to this user."""
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

and this is `send_mail` function:

```
def send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list,
              fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None,
              connection=None, html_message=None):
    """
    Easy wrapper for sending a single message to a recipient list. All members
    of the recipient list will see the other recipients in the 'To' field.

    If auth_user is None, use the EMAIL_HOST_USER setting.
    If auth_password is None, use the EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD setting.

    Note: The API for this method is frozen. New code wanting to extend the
    functionality should use the EmailMessage class directly.
    """
    connection = connection or get_connection(
       username=auth_user,
       password=auth_password,
       fail_silently=fail_silently,
    )
    mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, connection=connection)
    if html_message:
        mail.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')

    return mail.send()
```

There is a `html_message` attribute at first I think it handles like attachments to email but I test it and it worked.

This is my code that send html email:

```
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        subject = 'Activate Your Account'
        message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        user.email_user(subject, '', html_message=message)
```

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#send-mail):

> html_message: If html_message is provided, the resulting email will be a multipart/alternative email with message as the text/plain content type and html_message as the text/html content type